# Down Sides to Using Properties as Opposed to Method Variables

Tags: c#, methods, properties

I am debating the pros and cons of a couple of utility classes I have. The classes have a couple of properties which are set prior to calling the class methods. However, I was wondering if there are any cons to this approach rather than sending a variable along with the method call? There are typically only one or two methods in these classes.

Thank you.

Comment: This type of question might be more suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, Asad. I’ll post there as well.

Comment: Please post the relevant code

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your class looks like, so I'll make a guess...

I assume you have something like that:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static int X { get; set; }

    public static void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("X = {0}", X);
    }
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
MyClass.X = 42;
MyClass.MyMethod();
```

There are at least two problems with this approach:

- there is no obvious indication that you need to set `X` before calling `MyMethod`
- it makes the method non thread-safe: if both thread1 and thread2 are calling it, you can have something like that:

  thread1 sets X to 42
  thread2 sets X to 99
  thread1 calls MyMethod => prints 99 instead of 42
  thread2 calls MyMethod => prints 99

A better approach is to pass the value as a parameter to the method:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void MyMethod(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("X = {0}", x);
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
MyClass.MyMethod(42);
```

This solves the two problems mentioned before:

- it's clear than you need to provide the value of `x` to `MyMethod`
- there is no state stored in the class, so the method is thread-safe

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. I understand those concerns and they are valid concerns. However, isn’t that the case with all properties? SO why use those anyway other than to provide a variable accessible to the whole class? And if that is the case why use public properties at all? But I do like your rationale.

Comment: @physics90, there are two things to consider here: a) mutable vs immutable state, b) instance vs static state. Exposing immutable state through properties is OK, because since it can't be changed, you can't have bugs due to the state changing unexpectedly. Mutable instance state is often necessary, because some objects are implicitly stateful (e.g. UI controls). However, mutable static state should be avoided as much as possible, because it can easily cause bugs if you're not careful, as shown in the example above. So in general, you should avoid *static* properties unless they're readonly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it mostly depends on how you tend to invoke those methods. There are situations where either approach might be preferred.

When you tend to pass the same values over multiple invocations, it may be more convenient to instantiate a class which holds those values as properties, read-only or writable depending on the exact needs. You can then call your method multiple times conveniently without repeating yourself much. A good example of this is the `HttpClient`: you configure it once, and then call certain methods multiple times.

This approach also works well if you need to maintain some state between method invocations.

However, **by default**, if the above considerations do not apply, I would recommend having pure static methods. They are self-contained, they don't behave differently based on relatively external factors (property values set some time ago). You don't need to worry before each call whether you've set the properties correctly, as all the values are passed in. Finally, self-contained methods are easier to understand and use in multi-threading scenarios.